Is there a way to get more than 1000 Packages and versions from Azure DEVOPs Feed RESTAPI for GET Packages?
Is there a way to get more than 1000 Packages and versions from Azure DEVOPs Feed RESTAPI for GET Packages?
I have around 1400 ADO NUGET Packages and its versions to migrate.
I am running the REST API documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1 using Python.
It is limiting at 1000 packages without any warning.
It is nowhere documented as well.
The HTTP Response header parameter x-ms-continuationtoken for response continuity is not there in the API version 7.1.
How can I get the details and download all the ADO Packages?

The REST API that you are using has a skip parameter, $skip. Note that the skip parameter has a dollar sign in its name. Without it, the query will always return the same first 1000 results and won't tell you that your parameter name is invalid.
So, you can get all 1400 by calling it twice.

The first call would return the first 1000 packages
In the second call set the value of skip to 1000 ($skip=1000), and it should then return the remaining 400

Your URL should look something like this:
https://feeds.dev.azure.com/<org>/_apis/Packaging/Feeds/<feed-id>/Packages?api-version=7.1&$skip=1000

Thanks for sharing. This is helpful. This parameter is for dual purpose alongwith another prarameter. I am using $top as well to filter the number of versions less then 100. I can do that separately in excel. Thanks for quick one

The skip parameter doesn't seem to work for me. No matter what I set it to, I get the same first 1000 packages.

Never mind, you have to use $skip and I was using skip
